# disable comboboxlist with a click of a radiobutton asp.net

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

Am trying to disable my `comboboxlist` when I press a specific selection from my `radiobutton list`, or re-enable the `comboboxlist` If I make a different selection from `radiobuttonlist`.
Am using `postpacks` in my asp as well, but am I cant find how to make this work.
When I double click the `radiobutton list` and I get the automatic method generation.

I don't know what kind of attributes should I use to make the `radiobuttons` work when changed. 
I tried a few combinations but none seems to work.
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `AutoPostBack="true"` property as follow

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="docList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="loginUser" />
```

Comment: i fixed my problem. I didnt have a postback = true and my method worked fine. I had this in my code     Protected Sub radioButList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles radioButList.SelectedIndexChanged
 plus the autopostback = true and it works. cheers m8